# Why does SqlCommand not pass parameter inside a HASHBYTES function?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a simple `SqlConnection` code, which has a **HASHBYTES** function in it to retrieve data from my server.

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();

    using (var command = new SqlCommand(commandString, connection))
    {
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("mail", email));
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("password", password));
        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                return true;
            }
            throw new InvalidDataException();
        }
    }
}
```

The **commandString** property looks like this:

```
DECLARE @pass varchar(50);
SET @pass = @password;

DECLARE @pwdHash varbinary(max);
SET @pwdHash = HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', @pass);

SELECT * FROM Users
WHERE email=@mail AND pwd=@pwdHash;
```

This code works, but why doesn't the shorter code below work?

In the case below, the function doesn't go inside the while loop and instead throws an exception.

```
DECLARE @pwdHash varbinary(max);
SET @pwdHash = HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', @password);

SELECT * FROM Users
WHERE email=@mail AND pwd=@pwdHash;
```

In both of these codes, the **@password** value is set as a `SqlParameter`, so it should work, right? Or am I missing something?

Comment: What is the actual difference at runtime? "It doesn't work" is not a descriptive statement. Does it crash/throw an exception? Return zero?

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: Sorry, with the upper code, it returns true, and with the code below it doesn't hit the while loop so it throws an exception.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

String parameters are passed as `nvarchar` by default; but your longer command casts `@password` to `varchar` which has a different binary representation and so would generate a different hash digest which would not match your existing records if their hashes were generated differently.

BTW, you should salt your hashes too.

Comment: Excellent answer! 6 minutes and you get the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the shorter code, change the datatype for @password to `VARCHAR`
Works fine.